# STO for Time sensitive Campaigns?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, einstein, triggered-send

How would Send Time Optimization work in Time sensitive case?

If the offer is applicable only for 2 hours then STO will not work.

Please correct if my understanding is wrong. Also STO campaign works for the 24hr window?

Answer (score 0):

This would not be a use case for STO, if you have a two hour window. With a two hour window you would only have two send times (STO only sends at the top of the hour), so the likely hood a subscriber has an optimized send time of those two choices is low.

STO Campaign has some preset windows, and currently also a [custom sliding window](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2020_einstein_sto_updates.htm&type=5)

> Einstein Send Time Optimization (STO) now lets you select the best window of time for your email send. Selecting a custom window provides flexibility when you’re sending shorter promotional campaign sends or observe 2–6 day windows. You can also control how Einstein STO handles contacts who don’t have enough data to create a personalized model by setting a default for unmodeled contacts.